# Hybris convert all attributes using CmsItemConverter

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, populate, converters

I've created a custom component with these attributes:

CustomComponent

- String id
- Integer sku
- String color
- List variants
- Price price

Variant and price are custom objects.

When this CmsComponent gets populated and converted using the DefaultCmsItemConverter OOTB :

`de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.rendering.populators.CMSComponentModelToDataRenderingPopulator#populate (line 46)`

`de.hybris.platform.cmsfacades.cmsitems.converter.DefaultCMSItemConverter#convert(de.hybris.platform.core.model.ItemModel)`

It only populates simple attributes like id, sku and color. The Custom Objects like Price and Variants doesn't populate into `componentData.setOtherProperties(getCmsItemConverter().convert(componentModel));`

How can I get a complete population including inner Object attributes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps are:

1. Create new `Populator` for `variants` and `price`
2. Assign the newly created `Populator` to the existing `Converter`

Check https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=294094358 for an example.

**Update:** one of the following should work for you

```
<bean parent="modifyPopulatorList"> 
    <property name="list" ref="cmsItemConverter" /> 
    <property name="add" ref="myPopulatorVariantAndPrice" /> 
</bean>
```

or

```
<bean parent="modifyPopulatorList"> 
    <property name="list" ref="cmsItemConverterCustomPopulators" /> 
    <property name="add" ref="myPopulatorVariantAndPrice" /> 
</bean>
```

Comment: I see that there is a list of populators (OOTB) that populates the values :

<alias name="defaultCmsItemConverterCustomPopulators" alias="cmsItemConverterCustomPopulators" />
 <util:list id="defaultCmsItemConverterCustomPopulators">
  <ref bean="cmsItemDefaultAttributesPopulator" />
  <ref bean="cmsItemUniqueIdentifierAttributePopulator" />
 </util:list>

How can I add via spring xml my new populators variant and price populator to this list ?

Comment: I've tried something like this:
 <bean parent="modifyPopulatorList">
        <property name="list" ref="defaultCmsItemConverterCustomPopulators" />
        <property name="add" ref="myPopulatorVariantAndPrice" />
    </bean>

But the ide tells me that : "Bean must be of 'de.hybris.platform.converters.PopulatorList<SOURCE,TARGET>' type "

Comment: It worked ! Now I have another problem , can you check this question please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176963/hybris-ootb-bean-is-not-being-injected